# Working powershell function does not do his job when calling from C#

Tags: c#, powershell

Looks like i explained my problem not good enough. So here my Edit:

I have a powershell function for unpinning the windows start menu tiles.
Going from this: [imgur.com/a/0hRhDkW](https://imgur.com/a/0hRhDkW) 
to this: [imgur.com/a/rMCkfR9](https://imgur.com/a/rMCkfR9)

The function does what she should, works fine without any errors.
I can call the *.ps1 file via bat like this:

```
    c:\Windows\System32\windowspowershell\v1.0\powershell.exe -NoProfile -executionpolicy remotesigned -File "C:\Users\%username%\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\self-deleting-script_user-settings.ps1"
```

or just start it via powershell ISE.

So this is the powershell function we are talking about:

```
    function UnpinTiles
    {
        (New-Object -Com Shell.Application).
            NameSpace('shell:::{4234d49b-0245-4df3-b780-3893943456e1}').
            Items() | %{ $_.Verbs() } | ?{$_.Name -match 'Un.*pin from Start'} | %{$_.DoIt()}
    }
```

The function is part of a User-config-script.
Maybe someone is interested in the whole thing. Here you go:

```
    #Info#
    #   administative privileges are needed, to write to locations that are shared by multiple users.
    #   therfore, you can only write to HKEY_CURRENT_USER and that's all we need!
    #Info#



    ## load into memory, Self deleting
    Remove-Item $MyINvocation.InvocationName


    ## Window Design
    [console]::ForegroundColor = "Blue"
    [console]::BackgroundColor = "White"
    #title
    $host.ui.RawUI.WindowTitle = "Flex - Configure User"
    cls

    #-------------------------------------------------------------#



    ## unpin all start menu tiles (english only. maybe change ?{$_.Name -match 'Un.*pin from Start'} for different language)
    function UnpinTiles
    {
        (New-Object -Com Shell.Application).
            NameSpace('shell:::{4234d49b-0245-4df3-b780-3893943456e1}').
            Items() | %{ $_.Verbs() } | ?{$_.Name -match 'Un.*pin from Start'} | %{$_.DoIt()}
    }


    #----------------------RegTweaks-START----------------------#
    ##________________________________________________________________________Format
    #Write-Host "   what i am doing" -ForegroundColor Gray
    #If (!(Test-Path "HKCU:\")) {
    #    New-Item -Path "HKCU:\" >$null 2>&1
    #}
    #Set-ItemProperty -Path "HKCU:\" -Name "" -Type DWord -Value 0 >$null 2>&1
    ##________________________________________________________________________Format


    try 
    {

    #Error Silent
    $ErrorActionPreference = 'SilentlyContinue'
        function RegTweaks
        {
            #Disable Windows Hello Notifications
            Write-Host "    Disable Windows Hello Notifications" -ForegroundColor Gray
            If (!(Test-Path "HKCU:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Notifications\Settings\Windows.SystemToast.HelloFace")) {
                New-Item -Path "HKCU:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Notifications\Settings\Windows.SystemToast.HelloFace" >$null 2>&1
            }
            Set-ItemProperty -Path "HKCU:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Notifications\Settings\Windows.SystemToast.HelloFace" -Name "Enabled" -Type DWord -Value 0 >$null 2>&1

            #Disable News Notifications
            Write-Host "    Disable News Notifications" -ForegroundColor Gray
            If (!(Test-Path "HKCU:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Notifications\Settings\Microsoft.BingNews_8wekyb3d8bbwe!AppexNews")) {
                New-Item -Path "HKCU:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Notifications\Settings\Microsoft.BingNews_8wekyb3d8bbwe!AppexNews" >$null 2>&1
            }
            Set-ItemProperty -Path "HKCU:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Notifications\Settings\Microsoft.BingNews_8wekyb3d8bbwe!AppexNews" -Name "Enabled" -Type DWord -Value 0 >$null 2>&1

            #Disable Edge Notifications
            Write-Host "    Disable Edge Notifications" -ForegroundColor Gray
            If (!(Test-Path "HKCU:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Notifications\Settings\Microsoft.MicrosoftEdge_8wekyb3d8bbwe!MicrosoftEdge")) {
                New-Item -Path "HKCU:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Notifications\Settings\Microsoft.MicrosoftEdge_8wekyb3d8bbwe!MicrosoftEdge" >$null 2>&1
            }
            Set-ItemProperty -Path "HKCU:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Notifications\Settings\Microsoft.MicrosoftEdge_8wekyb3d8bbwe!MicrosoftEdge" -Name "Enabled" -Type DWord -Value 0 >$null 2>&1

            #Disable Suggested Notifications
            Write-Host "    Disable Suggested Notifications" -ForegroundColor Gray
            If (!(Test-Path "HKCU:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Notifications\Settings\Windows.SystemToast.Suggested")) {
                New-Item -Path "HKCU:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Notifications\Settings\Windows.SystemToast.Suggested" >$null 2>&1
            }
            Set-ItemProperty -Path "HKCU:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Notifications\Settings\Windows.SystemToast.Suggested" -Name "Enabled" -Type DWord -Value 0 >$null 2>&1

            #Disable Store Notifications
            Write-Host "    Disable Store Notifications" -ForegroundColor Gray
            If (!(Test-Path "HKCU:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Notifications\Settings\Microsoft.WindowsStore_8wekyb3d8bbwe!App")) {
                New-Item -Path "HKCU:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Notifications\Settings\Microsoft.WindowsStore_8wekyb3d8bbwe!App" >$null 2>&1
            }
            Set-ItemProperty -Path "HKCU:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Notifications\Settings\Microsoft.WindowsStore_8wekyb3d8bbwe!App" -Name "Enabled" -Type DWord -Value 0 >$null 2>&1

            #Disable Security and Maintenance Notifications
            Write-Host "    Disable Security and Maintenance Notifications" -ForegroundColor Gray
            If (!(Test-Path "HKCU:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Notifications\Settings\Windows.SystemToast.SecurityAndMaintenance")) {
                New-Item -Path "HKCU:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Notifications\Settings\Windows.SystemToast.SecurityAndMaintenance" >$null 2>&1
            }
            Set-ItemProperty -Path "HKCU:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Notifications\Settings\Windows.SystemToast.SecurityAndMaintenance" -Name "Enabled" -Type DWord -Value 0 >$null 2>&1

            #Disable Hotkey to Toggle Color Filters On or Off in Windows 10
            Write-Host "    Disable Hotkey to Toggle Color Filters On or Off in Windows 10" -ForegroundColor Gray
            If (!(Test-Path "HKCU:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\ColorFiltering")) {
                New-Item -Path "HKCU:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\ColorFiltering" >$null 2>&1
            }
            Set-ItemProperty -Path "HKCU:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\ColorFiltering" -Name "HotkeyEnabled" -Type DWord -Value 0 >$null 2>&1

            #Add This PC Desktop Icon
            Write-Host "    Add This PC Desktop Icon" -ForegroundColor Gray
            If (!(Test-Path "HKCU:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\HideDesktopIcons\NewStartPanel")) {
                New-Item -Path "HKCU:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\HideDesktopIcons\NewStartPanel" >$null 2>&1
            }
            Set-ItemProperty -Path "HKCU:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\HideDesktopIcons\NewStartPanel" -Name "{20D04FE0-3AEA-1069-A2D8-08002B30309D}" -Type DWord -Value 0 >$null 2>&1

            #Taskbar, Hide Task View Button
            Write-Host "    Taskbar, Hide Task View Button" -ForegroundColor Gray
            If (!(Test-Path "HKCU:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Advanced")) {
                New-Item -Path "HKCU:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Advanced" >$null 2>&1
            }
            Set-ItemProperty -Path "HKCU:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Advanced" -Name "ShowTaskViewButton" -Type DWord -Value 0 >$null 2>&1

            #Taskbar, Hide Search
            Write-Host "    Taskbar, Hide Search" -ForegroundColor Gray
            If (!(Test-Path "HKCU:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Search")) {
                New-Item -Path "HKCU:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Search" >$null 2>&1
            }
            Set-ItemProperty -Path "HKCU:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Search" -Name "SearchboxTaskbarMode" -Type DWord -Value 0 >$null 2>&1

            #Show File Name Extensions
            Write-Host "    Show File Name Extensions" -ForegroundColor Gray
            If (!(Test-Path "HKCU:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Advanced")) {
                New-Item -Path "HKCU:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Advanced" >$null 2>&1
            }
            Set-ItemProperty -Path "HKCU:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Advanced" -Name "HideFileExt" -Type DWord -Value 0 >$null 2>&1

            #Prevent Sticky Keys
            Write-Host "    Prevent Sticky Keys" -ForegroundColor Gray
            If (!(Test-Path "HKCU:\Control Panel\Accessibility\StickyKeys")) {
                New-Item -Path "HKCU:\Control Panel\Accessibility\StickyKeys" >$null 2>&1
            }
            Set-ItemProperty -Path "HKCU:\Control Panel\Accessibility\StickyKeys" -Name "Flags" -Type String -Value 506 >$null 2>&1

            #Make Desktop Menus Appear Faster
            Write-Host "    Prevent Sticky Keys" -ForegroundColor Gray
            If (!(Test-Path "HKCU:\Control Panel\Desktop")) {
                New-Item -Path "HKCU:\Control Panel\Desktop" >$null 2>&1
            }
            Set-ItemProperty -Path "HKCU:\Control Panel\Desktop" -Name "MenuShowDelay" -Type String -Value 200 >$null 2>&1

            #Taskbar, Hide People Button
            Write-Host "    Prevent Sticky Keys" -ForegroundColor Gray
            If (!(Test-Path "HKCU:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Advanced\People")) {
                New-Item -Path "HKCU:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Advanced\People" >$null 2>&1
            }
            Set-ItemProperty -Path "HKCU:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Advanced\People" -Name "PeopleBand" -Type String -Value 0 >$null 2>&1
        }    
    }
    catch 
    {}
    #------------------------RegTeaks-END-----------------------#








    #==========================================
    # EXECUTION 
    #==========================================
    cls
    $EXcount = 1
    Write-Host "        ========================================" -ForegroundColor Black
    Write-Host "        =========== Configuring User ===========" -ForegroundColor Black
    Write-Host -NoNewline "        ====== " -ForegroundColor Black
    Write-Host -NoNewline "Do not close this window!!" -ForegroundColor Red
    Write-Host " ======" -ForegroundColor Black
    Write-Host "        ========================================" -ForegroundColor Black
    Write-Host "`n"

    ## unpin all start menu tiles
    Write-Host "`n$EXcount. Unpin StartMenu tiles."
    $EXcount++
    UnpinTiles
    Write-Host -NoNewline "______________________________________________________|"
    Write-Host "Done!" -ForegroundColor Green


    ##Registry tweaks
    Write-Host "`n$EXcount. Adding Registry Tweaks"
    $EXcount++
    RegTweaks
    Write-Host -NoNewline "______________________________________________________|"
    Write-Host "Done!" -ForegroundColor Green
```

Now to my Problem.
Like is said everything works fine, just not when i try to call the *.ps1 from a C# program like this:

```
    Process.Start("C:\\Windows\\System32\\windowspowershell\\v1.0\\powershell.exe", $"-ExecutionPolicy ByPass -File {PathToFile}");
```

The functions runs through but the windows start menu tiles are still there.
And i have to clue why the hell he can't do it.

So

- i call it via bat, it can remove the windows start menu tiles.
- i call it via C#, it can not remove the windows star menu tiles.

Comment: how about showing us the relevant parts of the powershell function? And what do you mean by "does not do his job"? What does it then?

Comment: that is the whole function, that is all of it.
you can test it yourself, it removes all your pinned entries from the start menu. 
from this: https://imgur.com/a/0hRhDkW
to this: https://imgur.com/a/rMCkfR9

Comment: You're never calling the function in your script; you're only defining it.

Comment: What's "PathToFile"?  Does it contain an environment variable `%username%` like your "bat" example?  If so, you should call `System.Environment.ExpandEnvironmentVariables` to expand environment variables.

Comment: tried it, was not susseccful

`
PsFileName = SourceFilePath.SafeFileName;

private string DesPath = Path.GetTempPath();
DesPathScript = DesPath + "script";

string sd = DesPathScript + "\\" + PsFileName;

#edit
Environment.ExpandEnvironmentVariables(sd);
Process.Start("C:\\Windows\\System32\\windowspowershell\\v1.0\\powershell.exe", $"-ExecutionPolicy ByPass -File {sd}");

`

That's the tool i am working on, please mention i am still new in c#
https://imgur.com/a/EZws8mh

Answer (score 0):

If this …

```
PathToFile
```

… is the full UNC to the script with this function in it, then as noted by TheIncorrigible1, you are just calling the script, not the function in it, until you change what you posted to this.

```
function UnpinTiles
{
    (New-Object -Com Shell.Application).
        NameSpace('shell:::{4234d49b-0245-4df3-b780-3893943456e1}').
        Items() | %{ $_.Verbs() } | ?{$_.Name -match 'Un.*pin from Start'} | %{$_.DoIt()}
}

# Call the function
UnpinTiles
```

If you just want to run that block when you call the script, then just do this.

```
(New-Object -Com Shell.Application).
NameSpace('shell:::{4234d49b-0245-4df3-b780-3893943456e1}').
Items() | 
%{ $_.Verbs() } | 
?{$_.Name -match 'Un.*pin from Start'} | 
%{$_.DoIt()}
```

If you are saying, there are multiple function in the script, then you run the file to load the script that you still have to call the function as what TheIncorrigible1 is suggesting.